# Accessing multiple AWS accounts using boto3 without secret key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I wrote a python script which is deployed in a EC2 Instance and lets say this EC2 reside in AWS account **A1**. Now my script from **A1** want to access 10 other AWS account.

And remember I don't have any `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` or `SECRET_KEY` of any account cause using `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` or `SECRET_KEY` is strictly prohibited here.

I can easily do that if I have access key. But I can't figure it out how can I do that without access key?

Is there any possible way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The EC2 should assume an IAM Role.

Then log in to all your 10 other accounts and create roles there. These roles should give cross account access to the EC2 instance role. It is also in these roles that you define what permissions the EC2 instance should have.

Answer (score 1):

Storing `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` in your code or EC2 instances is generally considered a bad practice.

You should handle permissions by attaching an IAM Role to the EC2 instance that is running your business logic ([Docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html)).

By doing that you will then need an appropriate IAM Role that has enough rights to perform the actions you need in the other accounts ([Docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You can do by assuming an IAM role. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html

Comment: Assuming an IAM Role still requires the code/EC2 to have credentials/IAM Role that is allowed to assume these roles.